# Trying to create a scorelist table in MySQL, but the performance is bad

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a big performance problem with a highscore list in mysql. Basically we have users, we have games and users can play games and get scores in those games.
We want to have a toplist which is browsable with customizable filters, so a user can either display all scores or filter it by game X or other factors.
Unfortunately the current list is totally not performant. It has currently, lets say, a half million datasets and our select query takes 20+ seconds which is way too long.

This is the current table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `score` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, # just an AI id
  `userid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, # foreign key for `users` table
  `gameid` varchar(255) NOT NULL, # foreign key for `games` table
  `date` date NOT NULL, # date of score
  `score` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL, # total score
  `score_level1` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL, # score in level 1
  `score_level2` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL, # score in level 2
  `score_level3` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL, # score in level 3
  `score_level4` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL, # score in level 4
  `score_level5` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL, # score in level 5
  `times_played` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL, # this is the n-th time the user plays this game (I want to know which score was his 1st try, which score was his 5th try etc)
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_game_date` (`userid`,`gameid`,`date`), # we save only the latest score per user per game per day (this unique index is for "replace into")
  UNIQUE KEY `user_game_times` (`userid`,`gameid`,`times_played`), # obviously a user cant play the game multiple times for the 3rd time
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ADD CONSTRAINT `score_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`userid`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
ADD CONSTRAINT `score_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`gameid`) REFERENCES `games` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Our select query looks like this:

```
SELECT `users`.`name` AS `username`, # we want to display who got a certain score
    `users`.`country` AS `country`, # we want to display country of a user. also users can filter the scorelist to display "italy only" for example
    `games`.`name` AS `gamename`, # show which game score is for
    `score`.`score` AS `score`, # the score, obviously
    `score`.`score_level1` AS `score1`, # display which score the user got in every level
    `score`.`score_level2` AS `score2`,
    `score`.`score_level3` AS `score3`,
    `score`.`score_level4` AS `score4`,
    `score`.`score_level5` AS `score5`,
    `score`.`times_played` AS `times_played`, # show how many attempts a user needed to achieve this very score
FROM `score`
INNER JOIN ( # this inner query is to make that we only display the latest score per user per game (yes, we do NOT want to display the highest score, but the latest). we need to keep the old data in the database though to display the score progress to the user on a different page
    SELECT `userid`,
        `gameid`,
        MAX(`date`) AS `date`
    FROM `score`
    GROUP BY `userid`, `gameid`
    ORDER BY `score` DESC
) `temp` ON `score`.`userid` = `temp`.`userid` AND `score`.`gameid` = `temp`.`gameid` AND `score`.`date` = `temp`.`date`
INNER JOIN `users` ON (`users`.`id` = `score`.`userid`)
INNER JOIN `games` ON (`games`.`id` = `score`.`gameid`)
$filter # php variable to filter. this can be empty or contain something like "where `gameid` = 4" or "where `users`.`country` = 'it'"
LIMIT :limit,:limit2 # this is done by paging function. we display 50 entries per page. (e.g. "0, 50" for page 1, "50, 50" for page 2 etc)
```

explained select query:

```
id  select_type     table       type        possible_keys               key         key_len     ref                     rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY     <derived2>  ALL         NULL                    NULL        NULL        NULL                    585106  
1   PRIMARY     users       eq_ref      PRIMARY                 PRIMARY     4       temp.userid                 1   
1   PRIMARY     games       eq_ref      PRIMARY                 PRIMARY     767         temp.gameid                 1   
1   PRIMARY     score       eq_ref      user_game_date,user_game_times,games    user_game_date  774         temp.userid,games.id,temp.date      1   Using where
2   DERIVED     score       index       NULL                    user_game_date  774         NULL                    608211  Using temporary; Using filesort
```

profiling of select query (with limit "0,50" and `$filter` being empty):

```
Status              Duration
starting            0.000018
Waiting for query cache lock    0.000003
checking query cache for query  0.000063
checking permissions        0.000004
checking permissions        0.000002
checking permissions        0.000002
checking permissions        0.000003
Opening tables          0.000023
System lock             0.000035
optimizing          0.000005
statistics          0.000010
preparing           0.000008
Creating tmp table      0.000009
Sorting for group       0.000004
executing           0.000002
Copying to tmp table        0.194463
converting HEAP to MyISAM   0.042438
Copying to tmp table on disk    1.630471
Sorting result          16.097164
Sending data            0.061229
converting HEAP to MyISAM   0.805552
Sending data            7.414902
removing tmp table      1.944732
Sending data            0.000023
Waiting for query cache lock    0.000003
Sending data            0.000007
init                0.028244
optimizing          0.000026
statistics          0.000037
preparing           0.000024
executing           0.000004
Sending data            0.000539
end                 0.000008
query end           0.000005
closing tables          0.000002
removing tmp table      2.130069
closing tables          0.000028
freeing items           0.000684
logging slow query      0.000005
logging slow query      0.000004
cleaning up             0.000005
```

so how could I improve to get decent performance? do you have any suggestions for changes to either the select query ot the table structure? I don't mind major changes to the structure, as long as it helps with the performance

Answer (score 0):

A few things.

1. Since you don't care about sql injection, put you $filter inside
   your subselect.
2. Consider indexing on columns that you filter on.

Once you get that to work, avoid sql injection. Read up on
[PHP: Prepared statements and stored procedures](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: I actually do care about sql injections! Just one example for `$filter` would be `WHERE users.country = :country` and :country is bound later.
Also thanks for your tip about setting indexes. Should I only set indexes on stuff I use `WHERE` on or also for the `ORDER BY` rows (here: `score`)?

Comment: Also: I can't really put the `$filter` into the subselect, since it may contain rows which aren't joined in the subselect. I'm not sure if it would be clever to move all joins inside the subselect. Let me know if I'm wrong!